# How to change chart in AnyChart library

Tags: android, kotlin, anychart

I am using `AnyChart` library for Android ([library](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android)). I added one chart to the layout like this:

```
<com.anychart.AnyChartView
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

In `fragment.kt` I set chart programmatically in this way:

```
binding.chart.setChart(chart1)
```

Everything works fine but I have a button to switch the chart to another and after changing I get the same chart. I use the same method as in initialization:

```
binding.chart.setChart(chart2)
```

Has anyone ever faced a similar problem? AnyChart doesn't allow to change the chart? (I have the same problem when I first set `chart2` and then switch to `chart1` so the problem isn't in `chart` variable.)